# Geoserver: how to filter a layer related to another layer?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers, wms, cql-filter

I have the following problem:

I have 2 vector layers from PostGIS datastores: ***"firepoints"*** and ***"threats"***. The corresponding tables "firepoints" and "threats" have IDs and other attributes. They are related via a foreign key **"id_firepoint"** in "threats" table. One threat can have multiple firepoints, but one firepoint can have only one threat.

What I need to do is to filter WMS layers in Openlayers using CQL filters: first I want to filter the ***"firepoints"*** layer using some attribute ("satellite", for example) and then apply the derived IDs to filter ***"threats"*** layer using the "id_firepoint" attribute.

The problem is that I don't know how to derive the list of IDs of filtered "firepoints".

I have tried using the Cross-layer filtering with "querylayer" module, but I don't think that I understood how to use it correctly.

This is the filter that I try to apply to the "GSS:threats" layer:

> id_firepoint IN queryCollection('GSS:firepoints','id','satellite =
>   AQUA')

Is there any way to filter a layer related to another layer using dynamically changing attributes?